# JQuery Validate Plugin - AllowIng Submission

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using the JQuery Validate plug in to validate some input forms, works great.

Have a form that one piece of information is desired but not required to submit the form.

Lets say for example the form has name, address and boat name.  Name and address are required to complete entry,  boat name is needed before the event but we don't want to hold up the entry if they don't know it yet.

Is there a easy way to use the Validate plug in to pop up a message that say something like:

Boat name must be supplied prior to the event, you may complete registration with out it but please ......  Then maybe have 2nd submit button that bypasses the JQ Validate routines??

Dave

Comment: Do you want the user to have to click on submit again after the pop up appeared ?

Comment: Yes something like that. Was thinking maybe a second submit button with word like Submit with missing info or something.

Answer (score 0):

You have not show us any code to work with here, but basically, you could do something like this...

There is no method available to turn validation on/off on demand.   Since the plugin is designed to handle the `click` and intercept the `submit` event, you could remove the second button from the form (to avoid a submit) and handle the data separately, using ajax to send the data to the server.

```
$('#save').click(function() {
    var data = $('#myform').serialize();
    // ajax code to send the serialized data to the server
});
```

**Simple DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/wnwT9/**